# pragma warning(push, 0) doesn't disable /Wall warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I recall this trick working some time in the past, but it doesn't seem to be working now.

Putting `#pragma warning(push, 0)` around `#include` statements doesn't actually prevent `/Wall` warnings from being generated from those included files.

Changing `/Wall` to `/W4` gets around the issue, but using `/Wall` seems to be broken.

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)

#include <iostream>

#pragma warning(pop)

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!";
}
```

Build output:

[image]

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.5.3

Full command line switches (generated from cmake):

```
/GS /TP /analyze- /Wall /Zc:wchar_t /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /Fd"main.dir\Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "NDEBUG" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX /Zc:forScope /GR /Gd /Oy- /MD /std:c++14 /Fa"Release/" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"main.dir\Release\" /Fp"main.dir\Release\main.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

I googled around and found a [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/891a02d2-d0cf-495a-bcea-41001cf599de/pragma-warningpush-0-cant-disable-wall-warning-on-visual-studio-2017?forum=vcgeneral) that seems to describe the same issue, but no solution was suggested. Hopefully folks here on StackOverflow have a better idea?

Comment: You have to report it the right way, the MSDN forum support staff won't forward it.  In VS use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.  Meanwhile, consider that /W4 is the only really practical setting, /Wall is far too chatty to be useful.  If you disable everything to work around that then there is no point to it anymore.  And that 0 is not documented as a proper value, only 1..4.  So #pragma warning(push, 4) for header files is a logical choice.

Comment: "consider that /W4 is the only really practical setting," That is not actually true, we use Wall on a codebase with millions of lines (with a few select suppressions), and its not that uncommon in my industry at all. There's a great article here about what MS are doing to make it easier to run with Wall https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/13/broken-warnings-theory/

Answer (score 3):

This appears to have been fixed for me in 15.9.1.